# Loop for check text in column

Tags: arrays, list, loops, for-loop, google-apps-script

I would like an example to check a column for "ok" text.

When text is found, I will give an instruction.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should try to do a little more research before posting questions, but here is a basic formula that will do what you need.

```
function checkColumn(theRange,textToFind) {
  for(var i=0;i<theRange.length;i++){
    if(theRange[i].includes(textToFind)){
        return true;
      }
    }
  return false;
}
```

[image]